# Configuring Django-compass2 on my project for first time

Tags: python, css, django, sass, compass-sass

Problem is fallowing!

I am trying to install Compass and add it to my Django project.
Here is app https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-compass2/0.2

I have successfully installed app with "pip" command, added 'djcompass' to apps in settings.py, but configuring settings.py is very hard for me.

What exactly is COMPASS_INPUT and COMPASS_OUTPUT? Do i need to make any files? Description is saying COMPASS_INPUT would have Sass stylesheets, but i don't know where to get them.

I have style.css and would like to use in it some compass commands.

Answer (score 0):

COMPASS_INPUT is the path to the directory of your .scss or .sass files that need to be converted into .css files.

COMPASS_OUTPUT is the path to the directory where the compiled .scss or .sass files should .css files in.

Comment: So COMPASS_OUTPUT needs to be where is my Style.css, but i don't get the INPUT! I wright everything in Style.css. Should i need another file? for example "@include box-sizing(border-box);" is input or output file?

Comment: Compass compiles SASS/SCSS stylesheets

Comment: i guess i understood. Style.css is OUTPUT and where i wright my code is for example raw_style.css is INPUT, but how will settings know with file it needs to open if i need to enter directory path?

Comment: http://sass-lang.com/guide - Follow this guide it should lead you in the right direction